# Trying to install owncloud on debian server, having some troubles

Tags: linux, debian, owncloud

I am trying to install owncloud on my debian server, but some packages causing some troubles. I'm not really used to Linux and could need some help solving the problem:

This is the command I'm using:

```
cd && apt-get update && 
apt-get -y install apache2 php5 php-pear php-xml-parser php5-sqlite php5-json \
sqlite php5-mysql mp3info curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl zip php5-gd wget \
&& wget http://owncloud.org/releases/owncloud-3.0.0.tar.bz2 && \
tar xfj owncloud-3.0.0.tar.bz2 && \
cp -r owncloud /var/www/ && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/owncloud && \ 
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

This is the error message i get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 initscripts : Breaks: console-setup (< 1.74) but 1.68+squeeze2 is to be installed
               Breaks: initramfs-tools (< 0.104) but 0.98.8 is to be installed
 klibc-utils : Breaks: initramfs-tools (< 0.103) but 0.98.8 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

So i guess i have dependency problems with initscripts and klibc-utils.

Here the full console output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php5-common' instead of 'php5-json'
Note, selecting 'libcurl4-openssl-dev' instead of 'libcurl3-dev'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 initscripts : Breaks: console-setup (< 1.74) but 1.68+squeeze2 is to be installed
               Breaks: initramfs-tools (< 0.104) but 0.98.8 is to be installed
 klibc-utils : Breaks: initramfs-tools (< 0.103) but 0.98.8 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Somebody has an idea how to solve the issue??

sources.list:

```
###############################################################################
# Hetzner mirror

deb     http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages squeeze main contrib non-free
deb     http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security squeeze/updates main contrib non-free



###############################################################################
# backup mirror
#

deb     http://cdn.debian.net/debian/  squeeze  main non-free contrib
deb-src http://cdn.debian.net/debian/  squeeze  main non-free contrib

deb     http://security.debian.org/  squeeze/updates  main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/  squeeze/updates  main contrib non-free

## backports
deb     http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free
deb     http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main contrib non-free

## Phpmyadmin
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

Comment: try to '-f install', update mirrors and try again

Comment: It sounds like you have been playing with `/etc/apt/sources,list`. The problem here is that some packages are newer than others. Could you post your sources.list so we can have a look please?

Comment: Please note that version 3.0.0 is really old already and not supported anymore! If possible, just use the repositories as specified in Temander's answer!

Answer (score 3):

http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:community&package=owncloud

The installation process is fairly straightforward now.

```
Add repository and install manually(hide)
```

For Debian 6.0 run the following as root:

echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:community/Debian_6.0/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud.list

apt-get update

apt-get install owncloud

---

You can add the repository key to apt like this:

wget 
apt-key add - < Release.key

Answer (score 0):

Let's start out by simplifying the situation.

First, run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.

If that works fine, then run `wget http://owncloud.org/releases/owncloud-3.0.0.tar.bz2 && tar xfj owncloud-3.0.0.tar.bz2 && cp -r owncloud /var/www/ && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/owncloud && /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.